# How do I search by attribute in DynamoDB?

Tags: dynamodb

I inherited a site that uses DynamoDB for its database, which I know nothing about unfortunately, and I'm trying to change a user's email for them.  There appears to be a users table in DynamoDB, but I don't know the user's id, only their username and current email, so at this point, I am just trying to find the record before updating it.  When I attempt to scan for these values in the web interface, I get no results; it just keeps searching.  If I scan in the web interface for an email address which I know exists, I also get no results.

Using these placeholder values,

```
Username: example
Email: example@example.com
```

I have tried a few commands using AWS CLI, but I get various errors:

```
aws dynamodb get-item --table-name users --key '{"Username": {"S": "example"}}'
```

This yields this error:

```
Unknown options: example}}', {S:
```

I have also tried this:

```
aws dynamodb query --table-name users --key-condition-expression "Username = :v1" --expression-attribute-values "{ \":v1\" : { \"S\" : \"example\" } }"
```

This yields this error:

```
An error occurred (ValidationException) when calling the Query operation: Query condition missed key schema element: id
```

I have also tried printing out all users, but it appears to fail for anything but the smallest tables:

```
aws dynamodb scan --table-name users
```

This yields this error:

```
An error occurred (ProvisionedThroughputExceededException) when calling the Scan operation (reached max retries: 2): The level of configured provisioned throughput for the table was exceeded. Consider increasing your provisioning level with the UpdateTable API.
```

Not sure what to do at this point.  Any advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I contacted AWS support, and they said two things:

1. The read/write capacity of the table needed to be changed from "provisioned" to "on-demand".
2. Scan is definitely the command to use here, not query; query requires the id, scan does not.

   ```
   aws dynamodb scan --table-name users --filter-expression "Username = :v1" 
       --expression-attribute-values "{ \":v1\" : { \"S\" : \"example\" } }"
   ```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like only the **key** or **global secondary indexes** can be efficiently searched in DynamoDB, which can be accomplished via the `query()` function, from my brief research. I'm honestly no DynamoDB expert, only have read up on it in the past, but this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/43355083/5059085) might be helpful for what you're trying to accomplish. Essentially it recommends creating a **global secondary index** on the field you're trying to use for searching.

Comment: Thanks for the help!  AWS support got back to me.  The answer was to change my table read/write capacity from provisioned to on-demand and to use scan instead of query, since query only operates with the id.  I appreciate your help though!

Comment: @kloddant No problem, unfortunately a lot of AWS's documentation is missing important details (despite them having a verbose set of documents). Usually I find questions pertaining to their products are best handled by their support team or your account rep. You can do a query like I mentioned but you'd have to implement the **GIS**, if you wanted a performant way to accomplish that, otherwise yes a **scan** of the entire table should work too.